# Trying to make a picture of an alien blink with a button not working

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import time
alien = Tk()
alien.title("Alien")
c = Canvas(alien, height=300, width=400)
c.pack()
body = c.create_oval(100, 150, 300, 250, fill="green")
eye = c.create_oval(170, 70, 230, 130, fill="white")
eyeball = c.create_oval(190, 90, 210, 110, fill="black")
mouth = c.create_oval(150, 220, 250, 240, fill="red")
neck = c.create_line(200, 150, 200, 130)
hat = c.create_polygon(180, 75, 220, 75, 200, 20, fill="blue")
def mouth_open():
    c.itemconfig(mouth, fill="black")
def mouth_close():
    c.itemconfig(mouth, fill="red")
def blink():
    c.itemconfig(eye, fill="green")
    c.itemconfig(eyeball, state=HIDDEN)
def unblink():
    c.itemconfig(eye, fill="white")
    c.itemconfig(eyeball, state=NORMAL)
def steal_hat():
    c.itemconfig(hat, state=HIDDEN)
    c.itemconfig(words, text="GIVE ME MY HAT BACK")
def burp():
    mouth_open()
    c.itemconfig(words, text="Burp!!!")
    time.sleep(1)
    c.itemconfig(words, text="I'm an alien!")
    mouth_close()
def blink2():
    blink()
    time.sleep(1)
    unblink()
def eye_control(event):
    key = event.keysym
    if key == "Up":
        c.move(eyeball, 0, -1)
    elif key == "Down":
        c.move(eyeball, 0, 1)
    elif key == "Left":
        c.move(eyeball, -1, 0)
    elif key == "Right":
        c.move(eyeball, 1, 0)
c.bind_all('<Key>', eye_control)
words = c.create_text(200, 280, text="I'm an alien!")
window = Tk()
window.title("Options")
btnBlink = Button(window, text="blink", command=blink2)
btnBlink.pack()
alien.mainloop()
window.mainloop()
```

I have made an alien and i want to make the user be able to steal the alien's hat, make the alien burp, make the alien blink and be able to move the alien's eyeballs. So far I have made it able to control his eyeballs but the blink isn't working. I have removed the time.sleep(1) in the defining for blink2 but that doesn't really change anything. **How would I make the alien able to blink.** Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `blink2`, it never calls for the canvas to be refreshed, so your alien appears to never blink.

You could fix this by removing `time.sleep(1)`, and using `after` for timing instead.

To implement this, `blink2` could look like this:

```
def blink2():
    blink()
    window.after(1000, unblink)  # Timing is in milliseconds.
```

Note that it is generally also convention to use `root` as reference to `Tk()`.

Comment: You made a little mistake trying to pass the `unblink` as a callback. Just remove redundant parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DarthFigo If this solved your problem could you mark it as answered? Thanks.